# Populate a Table Based on Certain Criteria

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

How do I populate the bolded table to the right with data like so? Trying to fill the table with dates and their associated cash flows based on location (without doing it manually or copy/pasting). Is there a formula? Already tried the FILTER and all the IF functions.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the Advanced Filter. It takes a little setup as you need to define 3 Named Ranges for easy execution.

1. Database - Your data table
2. Criteria - Your selection criteria.
3. Extract  - Where you want the matching data copied.

Also you have to use the exact names as in your Database for your Criteria and Extract ranges so you won't get the titles you want. However, you can overlay those cells with labeled shapes to solve the problem.

Once all this is done you can record a macro to create the code to run.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CashFlow()

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("A1:G7").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                   CriteriaRange:=Range("N2:N3"), _
                   CopyToRange:=Range("H2:I2"), Unique:=False

End Sub 'CashFlow
```

Now Simply by changing the value in N3 and rerunning the macro you can get a results for any location and the header in H1 will automatically change.
[image: Sample Workbook]